# why do I have to use --set-upstream when pushing a local branch

Tags: git

I acknowledge the fact that `--set-upstream` sets the default remote branch for the current local branch, which I can pull commits easier.
But let's say I don't want to track a remote branch because I just create a branch for a quick fix, so I just need to push it and ask the team leader to review it and merge it. I don't need to use git pull to get latest commits because no other team member will work on my branch locally. In this case I don't need to use `--set-upstream` but I'm still forced to use this otherwise I can't push my branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... In this case I don't need to use `--set-upstream`

Correct.

> but I'm still forced to use this ...

No, you're not *forced* to use it.  Use it if you want to, and don't use it if you don't want to.

If no upstream is set for the *current* branch *and* your `push.default` setting is `simple`,<sup>1</sup> you will have to spell out all the details:

```
git push origin somebranch
```

or if you prefer:

```
git push origin HEAD
```

because the `simple` setting requires that the current branch *have* an upstream when you omit the *refspec* argument (the `somebranch` or `HEAD` part of the above two commands).  Without an upstream, `simple` refuses to do the `git push`—but supplying a refspec overrides `simple`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The details here are somewhat version-dependent, as the *default* setting for `push.default` is different in Git 2.x vs Git 1.x.  If you have set your `push.default` explicitly to `simple`, though, even ancient Git versions should behave like Git 2.0 or newer.